# Using Model to equally distribute points, spatially within known geometry using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

Is it possible to create a model in ArcGIS ModelBuilder where you simply state number of points and an area in the form of a polygon to get the model to try and equally space out the points based on the geometry of the polygon and number of points?

Comment: Would you want to have multiple points in each polygon? In that case, what do you mean by "equally space out the points"?

Answer (score 1):

No out of the box tool, but can be done using arcpy. Picture shows 50 points inside polygon. Bold blue line shows polygon boundary. Pattern of points suits my understanding of equally distributed points  (could differ from yours):

[image]

SCRIPT:

```
import arcpy
## PARAMETERS TO CHANGE
source="LAKE"
target = 50
outFC=r"c:/scratch/equal_distance.shp"
# get polygon
g=arcpy.Geometry()
p=arcpy.Point()
POLYGON=arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(source, g)[0]
# get shape extent, calculate max. step
anExt=POLYGON.extent
stepMax = min(anExt.height,anExt.width)
yMin,yMax,xS,xE=anExt.YMin,anExt.YMax,anExt.XMin,anExt.XMax
low,high=0,stepMax
# use binary search to reach target number of points
while True:
    mid=(high+low)/2
##    just in case of no solution
    if (high-low) <0.01: break
    N=0
    yStep=mid/2*3.0**0.5
    iMax=int((yMax-yMin)/yStep)+2
    jMax=int((xE-xS)/mid)+2
    listOfPoints=[]
    for i in range(iMax):
        Y=yMin+i*yStep
        xStart=xS+i%2*mid/2
        xEnd = xE +i%2*mid/2
        for j in range(jMax):
            X=xStart+j*mid
            p.X,p.Y=X,Y
            dist=POLYGON.distanceTo(p)
            if dist>0:continue
            pGeom=arcpy.PointGeometry(p)
            listOfPoints.append(pGeom)
            N+=1
    arcpy.AddMessage("Number of points = %s" %N)
    if N==target:break
    if N<target:high=mid
    else:low=mid
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(listOfPoints,outFC)
```

Comment: This seems perfect, I will give it a go. Thank you!

Comment: Can this be made into a tool where I can select number of points and polygon before each time I run the script?

Comment: Yes it can be done easily. Will I do it for you? No.